# PHP: Saving POST reponse to a file

Tags: php, post

I am having a problem with saving a file from a response to a POST request.

I am using Google Charts API to create a chart using a POST request. I am then trying to save the result as an image.

I am following the API documentation as described here: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html

Here is my code:

```
$file = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
$file2 = fopen("test.png", 'w');

while (!feof($file)) {
    $buffer = fgets($file, 8192);
    fwrite($file2, $buffer);
}
fclose($file);
```

It saves the image partially, up to 20k or so, leaving the bottom part of the image unsaved.

(edit) Here is the working code, using curl:

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POST,count($request));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_string);
$data = curl_exec($handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it'll help, but what if you try using [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), instead of [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) -- the first being "binary safe", while the second stops at line ends... Considering you're trying to read from a binary stream, and not a text-file, maybe that can change something ?

If it doesn't change a thing, another idea would be to try using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), to download the file as a whole, instead of having to do some kind of loop.

And if it still doesn't work, what about [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) ?

Comment: Using fread instead of fgets gets the same result - only about half the file is saved.

Comment: strange, about `fread`/`fgets` ; but nice that curl worked :-)